# 2D descriptors for 3D objects

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want to recognize an object in an image. The image is given by a camera that observes a scene. So objects in the image are 3D objects, is it true?
Then, to do this can I use a 2D descriptor or I must use a 3D descriptor?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "objects in the image are 3D?" Are you using a Kinect? Objects in an image are, by definition, 2D. They are a "projection" of 3D entities onto a 2D plane. For object recognition/detection from 2D images, your descriptors are all 2D.

Comment: I have simple 2D images. OK, thanks